# How to handle multiple types of a json schema property in java objects?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema, pojo

I have the following JSON schema, where one of the properties is called `value`:

```
{
    "value": {
        "id": ".../properties/value",
        "type": ["number", "string", "null"],
        "title": "The Value Schema.",
        "description": "An explanation about the purpose of this instance.",
        "default": ""
    }
}
```

The JSON comes from a REST API.

What is the best way to handle this when converting to a POJO using Jackson?

Comment: You mean you want to convert this value to POJO? What are you expecting by "best way to handle"? please be a little clear so people can help you.

Comment: I am new to this so pls bear with me, but yes, basically what I am asking is, how to convert this part of the json object coming in from the api to the appropriate java type? Do I overload the methods in the pojo for the different types available in the json schema?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways -

1) Let there be a class to handle the inner json and make it part of the parent class (`has a`).

```
public class ParentsValue {
    String id; 
    List<String> type;
    // getters & setters.
    ...
}

public class Parent {
    ParentsValue value;
    // getters & setters.
    ...
}
```

2) Use a map.

```
public class Parent {
    Map<String, Object> value;
    // getters & setters.
    ...
}
```